# javascript map promises inside them

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise

I am having this code:

```js
signers.map(async (signer, tx) => {
   const address = await signer.getAddress();
   console.log(address);
   return { account: address, amount: 1 }
})

console.log("awesome");
```

The problem is that `awesome` gets printed first. How do I make sure that until all the promises are resolved inside `map`, it doesn't come to `awesome`.  The cleanest way would be much appreciated.

Comment: Add your solution as an answer, then (after the cooldown period) marked it as accepted.

Answer (score 7):

All async functions return a promise that resolves when the body of the function has completed or rejects when an exception occurs.

And, `.map()` is not `async-aware` at all.  It doesn't pause the loop waiting for the promise.  So, you are running all your asynchronous operations in-flight at the same time and `signers.map()` returns an array of promises.  If you want to know when they are all done and get the results of all those promises, you need to use `Promise.all()` on that array of promises.

```
let promises = signers.map(async (signer, tx) => {
   const address = await signer.getAddress();
   console.log(address);
   return { account: address, amount: 1 }
});

Promise.all(promises).then(results => {
    console.log("awesome");
    console.log(results);
}).catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
});
```

---

If, what you really want to do is to run your asynchronous operations serially, one after the other, then use a regular `for` loop in a containing `async` function because a `for` loop is `async-aware` and will pause the loop waiting for the `await`.

```
let addresses = [];
for (let signer of signers) {    
   const address = await signer.getAddress();
   console.log(address);
   addresses.push({ account: address, amount: 1 });
}
console.log(addresses);
```

Comment: @NikaKurashvili - Did this answer your question?

Answer (score 2):

Note that there is nothing stopping you from awaiting `Promise.all` since it's just a promise of results;

```
const promises = signers.map(async (signer, tx) => {
   const address = await signer.getAddress();
   console.log(address);
   return { account: address, amount: 1 }
});

const results = await Promise.all(promises);

console.log("awesome");
```